# Why won't JSON.parse() parse this?

Tags: javascript, html, json, debugging, dojo

I have JSON data and I am trying to parse it using `JSON.parse()`. I keep getting the error: `unexpected token o`. Could someone help?
I feel I should mention that I'm going to be using the parsed JSON data to populate a Dojo store which will then be used to populate a Dijit Tree. Would anyone recommend any other method to form a tree UI?

This is my code.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

require([
"dojo/ready", "dojo/_base/window", "dojo/json","dojo/dom","dojo/store/Memory", "dojo/store/Observable",
"dijit/tree/ObjectStoreModel", "dijit/Tree", "dojo/domReady!", "dojo/mouse","dojo/text!./data/all.json"],
 function(ready, win, JSON, dom, Memory, Observable, ObjectStoreModel, Tree, mouse, data){

var testStore = new Memory({

    data :  JSON.parse($("#getData").click(
            function(){
                  var inputString = "pspTreegetData{}";
                  var state =  Function that executes Tcl script and returns the JSON data
                  return state;
            })),
```

This is my Tcl script which gives the raw JSON data when I check its output,

```
proc pspTreegetData {} {
            set fo [open "C:/Path/To/File/sampleTest.json" r]
            set text [read $fo]
            close $fo
            puts $text 
            return $text
}
```

My Json file is as follows,

```
 [
{
    "name" : "root",
    "id"   : "rootNode",
    "description" : "This is the root node"
},

{
    "name"  : "level1_node1",
    "id"    : "l1n1", 
    "description" : "This is the first node of level 1",
    "parent" : "rootNode"
},

    { 
        "name"  : "level2_node1",
        "id"    :  "l2n1",
        "description" : "This is the first node of level 2",
        "parent" : "l1n1"
    },

    { 
        "name"  : "level2_node2",
        "id"    : "l2n2",
        "description" : "This is the second node of level 2",
        "parent" : "l1n1"
    },

        { 
            "name"    : "level3_node1",
            "id"      : "l3n1",
            "description" : "This is the first node of level 3",
            "parent" : "l2n2"
        },

        {
            "name"    : "level3_node2",
            "id"      : "l3n2",
            "description" : "This is the second node of level 3",
            "parent" : "l2n2"
        },

{ 
        "name"  : "level1_node2",
        "id"    : "l1n2",
        "description" : "This is the second node of level 1",
        "parent" : "rootNode"
},

{ 
        "name"  : "level1_node3",
        "id"    :  "l1n3",
        "description" : "This is the third node of level 1",
        "parent" : "rootNode"
},
        { 
            "name"  : "level2_node3",
            "id"    : "l2n3",
            "description" : "This is the third node of level 2",
            "parent" : "l1n3"
        },

        { 
            "name"  : "level2_node4",
            "id"    : "l2n4",
            "description" : "This is the fourth node of level 2",
            "parent" : "l1n3"
        },


{ 
        "name"  : "level1_node4",
        "id"   : "l1n4",
        "description" : "This is the fourth node of level 1",
        "parent" : "rootNode"
}
]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I keep getting the error : unexpected token o.

It means that you are trying to parse already parsed object. Just remove `JSON.parse()` and use input data as is.

Why "token o"? Because `JSON.parse()` runs `toString()` method on the provided input to make sure it is indeed of a String type. However when invoked on the object `toString()` produces a string `"[object Object]"`. The first character looks like array however the second one is definitely not something parsable. Hence the error.

**UPD.** You are seriously confusing things when you are trying to parse jQuery instance object - because this is what happens when you write `JSON.parse($("#getData").click());`. Despite of the `return state` line inside event object, you *can't return* from event listener function, because it's just doesn't make any sense. You bind event, it can happen in 5 minutes - of course script won't wait until it happens.

I'm not sure how exactly you load data, you only provided one line:

```
var state =  Function that executes Tcl script and returns the JSON data
```

but I'm pretty sure that "Function that executes Tcl script" either accepts callback function or returns thenable/promise object. In which case your code should look something like this:

```
require([
    "dojo/ready", "dojo/_base/window", "dojo/json", "dojo/dom", "dojo/store/Memory",
    "dojo/store/Observable", "dijit/tree/ObjectStoreModel", "dijit/Tree", "dojo/domReady!",
    "dojo/mouse", "dojo/text!./data/all.json"
], function(ready, win, JSON, dom, Memory, Observable, ObjectStoreModel, Tree, mouse, data) {

    $("#getData").click(function() {
        var inputString = "pspTreegetData{}";
        Function_that_executes_Tcl_script(function(data) {
            var testStore = new Memory({
                data: JSON.parse(data) // or if data is Object already just data: data 
            });
        })
    });

});
```

Comment: How is it parsed? I'm using this raw data! As I've shown you.

Comment: Probably because of the way you get the data (an xhr call maybe ?)

Comment: No. I'm using a Tcl script that gets this data by opening the file, storing it into a variable and returning it.

Comment: From your code I can see that you are trying to parse jQuery instance object: `JSON.parse($("#getData"))`. In this case of course you will get above error.

Comment: That's an event handler that returns the variable "state" which contains the JSON. I am not parsing a jQuery instance.

Comment: BTW, why mixing dojo and jquery ? `$(document).ready` is not needed thank to `dojo/domReady!` and `$("#getData").click` can be achieved using `dojo/on` (something like: `on(click, '#getData', function() {/*...*/})`)

Comment: @Aleph `$("#getData").click(function() { /* whatever return or not */ })` is going to be instance of jQuery constructor. Check `console.log( $("#getData").click(function() {}) instanceof jQuery`.

Comment: @ben, because I couldn't find any good tutorials or references for Dojo, and I'm comfortable with jQuery. Big mistake, I guess.

Comment: @Aleph did you look at dojo website ? http://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/#tutorials

Comment: @dsfq, so if I use `on(click, '#getData`, function() {...}))`, as @ben says, would I get a JSON file that could be parsed? Because I'm not getting anything, to be honest.

Comment: @Aleph Check updated answer, I tried to explain it better.

Comment: Thank you very much. This worked. I'm new to JavaScript. Appreciate the patience.

Answer (score 0):

Actually it look like you have the classical async issue...

Something like that sounds more reasonable...

```
$("#getData").click(function(){
    var inputString = "pspTreegetData{}";
    var state =  Function that executes Tcl script and returns the JSON data
    var testStore = new Memory({
        data :  JSON.parse(state),
 //...
```

Check this post:
[How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)